# copying arrays and pointers past the last element of the source using c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Would it be possible to initialize and array of double and then copy the contents into another array. The program should use a function using pointer notation to copy the original source array.

Example of the function call I am supposed to use would be copy_ptrs(copy, source, and a pointer to the element following the last element of the source.)

Here is my main for reference

```
int main() 
{
    int i, num; 
    double source[MAX];
    double target1[MAX];
    double target2[MAX];
    double target3[MAX];


    printf("\nEnter number of elements to be read into the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("\nEnter the values below (press enter after each entry)\n");

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) 
    {
            scanf("%lf", &source[i]);
    }

    copy_arr(target1, source, num);
    copy_ptr(target2, source, num);
    copy_ptrs(target3, source, source + num);//This is how I was instructed to call the function.


    printf("\n\nCopying Complete!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my pointer notation function for a simple copy

```
void copy_ptr(double target2[], double source[], int num)
{
    int i;
    double *p, *q;

    p = source;
    q = target2;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
            *q = *p;
        q++;
        p++;
    }

    printf("\n\n***The second function uses pointer notation to copy the elements***\n");
    printf("===================================================================\n");
    q = target2;

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {

        printf("\n              Pointer_Notation_Copy[%d] = %.2lf",i, *q++);
    }
}
```

Here is the other function to copy the source array using array notation

```
void copy_ptr(double target2[], double source[], int num)
{
    int i;
    double *p, *q;

    p = source;
    q = target2;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
            *q = *p;
        q++;
        p++;
    }

    printf("\n\n***The second function uses pointer notation to copy the elements***\n");
    printf("===================================================================\n");
    q = target2;

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {

        printf("\n              Pointer_Notation_Copy[%d] = %.2lf",i, *q++);
    }
}
```

When I try to add a 3rd function to satisfy the assignment I get stuck. How do I take a pointer to the element following the last element of the source?

```
void copy_ptrs(double target3[], double source[], int num)
{
    int i;
    double *p, *q;

    p = source;
    q = target3;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
            *q = *p;
        q++;
        p++;
    }

    printf("\n\n***The third function uses pointer notation to copy the elements + the number of elements read in?***\n");
    printf("===================================================================\n");
    q = target3;

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {

        printf("\n              Pointer_Notation_Copy[%d] = %.2lf",i, *q++);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your main has a bug, you ignore the return value of `scanf()`. Try this, when the program asks you to input the number of elements type `five`, and you will see what kind of mess will happen.

Comment: What does `copy_ptrs` do? Maybe the third argument is supposed to be like that (for example it copies while e.g. `ptr != end` where `end` is your third argument)?

Comment: Wellcome to SO. Please consult the help pages on what type of questions we want here and how to ask them. We are not here to do your assignment, but only to help you when you have a concrete technical problem. Voting to close.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. HW questions are fine here on SO, but you need to show us what effort you've put into solving it, and ask a specific question. Your question is essentially a request for code currently. Do you have any attempts at writing this function you can show us?

Comment: From the instructions.... have the third function take as arguments the name of the target, the name of the source and a pointer to the element following the last element of the source. All this to make a copy of the array I assume

Comment: its is 3 parter and no I have no code working at this time for the last function

Comment: void copy_ptr(double target2[], double source[], int num)
{
 int i;
 double *p, *q;
 
 p = source;
 q = target2;
 
 for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
 {
      *q = *p;
  q++;
  p++;
 }
 
 printf("\n\n***The second function uses pointer notation to copy the elements***\n");
 printf("===================================================================\n");
 q = target2;

 for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
 {
        
  printf("\n              Pointer_Notation_Copy[%d] = %.2lf",i, *q++);
 }
}

Comment: this is what I have for a straight pointer notation copy from an original source array

Comment: If you have additional information, please use the "edit" link just under the question tags to edit that information into your question. No one is going to try to decipher code left in a comment because the formatting is nonexistent.

Comment: sorry, using this site is new to me, I edited the information in my question.

Comment: By the way, you should read through (all, but especially) [this section of the SO help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Quote: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: It's alright. Everyone is new at some point. I thank you for taking the time to listen to our feedback. Your question is getting much better. The last thing to do is to narrow the focus of your question. It's good that you have your `copy_ptr` code included, but explain what is wrong with it. Does compilation fail? Do you get segfaults? Any error messages you can share?

Comment: let me make some more changes to my information

Comment: these two function work fine. The program compiles and executes properly

Answer (score 0):

Your statment:

> copy_ptrs(copy, source, and a pointer to the element following the last element of the source.)

and code:

```
void copy_ptr(double target2[], double source[], int num)
```

don't match.

Your call

```
copy_ptrs(target3, source, source + num);
```

does not match the function definition either.

You can change the function to:

```
void copy_ptr(double target2[], double* source, double* end)
```

to make it match with your statement and function call.

Then, you'll have to change the implementation to:

```
void copy_ptr(double target[], double* source, double* end)
{
   int i = 0;
   int num = end - source;
   double* p = source;
   double* q = target;

   for ( ; p != end; ++p, ++q)
   {
      *q = *p;
   }

   printf("\n\n***The second function uses pointer notation to copy the elements***\n");
   printf("===================================================================\n");

   q = target;
   for ( i = 0; i < num; ++i, ++q )
   {
      printf("\n              Pointer_Notation_Copy[%d] = %.2lf", i, *q);
   }
}
```